# Crystal C bindings: using fopen

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to use fopen for a library.
Is this the correct approach? Is fopen already defined somewhere? (it would be useful in LibC IMO)

```
@[Link("c")]
lib LibStd
  type File = Void*
  fun fopen( LibC::Char*, LibC::Char* ): File
  fun fclose( File )
end
```

It works fine, I would like to know the best way to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor improvement that could be useful (this is the current solution that I'm using in my bindings):

```
@[Link("c")]
lib LibStd
  type File = Void
  fun fopen( filename : LibC::Char*, mode : LibC::Char* ): File*
  fun fclose( stream : File* )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont bother with C. Just use Crystal:

`File.open(path) { |file| ... }`

If you ever need to access the file descriptor, you may call `file.fd`.

Comment: The C library that I'm using requires FILE* not a file descriptor

Comment: What's the library? Doesn't it have another option, like passing a path directly?

Comment: A vendor lib (V4L like) of a framegrabber device. I'm making some experiments :)

Comment: Then there is no solution. We only use `open` and file descriptors internally. You'll have to go with your solution above.